# Quotes in XSL: set image src using attribute

Tags: html, xml, xslt

In an XML data file I have a collection of images `<image_list>`; within this collection, I have images with different names (given in the `<image_result>` name attribute).

How can I escape the quotes so that this will work? I've tried using `&quot;` or `\"` for both sets of quotes, but emacs lights up red, indicating a formatting error.

**XSL snippet:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
<xsl:for-each select="image_list/image_result">
  <td>
    <img src ="<xsl:value-of select="name"/>" style="width:450px"/>
  </td>
</xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your XSLT needs to be a well-formed XML document, so the type of construct you're attempting is simply not possible. Use an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template) instead:

```
<img src="{name}" style="width:450px"/>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. It would have taken a long time to find the right thing to Google.

Comment: For some reason it only works when I do `<img src="{@name}" style="width:450px"/>`

Comment: @Oliver - Probably because `name` is an attribute in the source document.

Answer (score 2):

`<td>

    <img src="{name}" style="width:450px"/>

</td>`

should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`xsl:attribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256165.aspx):

```
<td>
  <img style="width:450px">
   <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
  </img>
</td>
```

Or the simplified option (using the [attribute value template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#dt-attribute-value-template)):

```
<td>
  <img src="{name}" />" style="width:450px"/>
</td>
```